# How do I fix a bad gateway error caused by simple logic in twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm making a webapp for an event with competitions, and need create/edit/delete buttons on the webpage so I don't need to do everything in the backend.

It's built on PHP/Symfony, and I use TWIG as the template handler.

In the TWIG files, I have the code `{% if is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") %}`; which works completely in my local environment.

But when I use the production environment, TWO instances of this `{% if is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") %}` logic make the page get an upstream error:

`2023/10/04 14:34:10 [error] 309322#309322: *230714 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: ***.***.**.**, server: ***, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock:", host: "***", referrer: "https://***/1/competition-locations"`

(website and IP address hidden)

I've found the cause, which is solely the `{% if is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") %}` line - the contents don't influence anything, and when I remove this line the page immediately works.

This only happens on TWO instances of this line, even though there are more than 25 in the whole project.

I've debugged it as far is I could (just removed the `{% if is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") %}` block completely) which obviously made the page work, but I need these buttons to exist, so I have no clue what could cause this error.

Honestly, I have 0 clue what causes this and how this ever could have happened, I've never had this problem before and even my boss who uses Symfony a lot doesn't know anything.

Comment: It sounds very likely that this has something to do with your web server configuration, since the bug only appears on production environment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using nginx for your prod environment.
May I suggest that you look into your nginx configuration?
The error message is most likely linked to a low buffer size.

Look into your `nginx.conf` or vhost for this part to adjust the corresponding values.

```
server {
 proxy_busy_buffers_size   512k;
 proxy_buffers   4 512k;
 proxy_buffer_size   256k;
 # rest of the nginx config below #
}
```

You can find more info about the config [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream/).